# BFS - WordChain/Wordladder

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, nodes, breadth-first-search

I need some help with a problem. I want to find the longest shortest path between some word and some given endword. All the words have are of length 4. I have a graph where each node represents a word and every word that is different in 1 position is connected.

I have a list with all the words. I have a proper function that finds the longest shortest path, but it starts from every word in the word list and then does a BFS from every word in the word list.

How can I, given some endword, find the word that has the longest shortest path to the given endword ?

By the longest shortest path I mean the shortest path from all words to endword and the longest path amongst them.

**How can I do this with just one BFS ?**

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the longest shortest path means. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a breadth-first search, you can tag each node in the graph with its distance (the length of the shortest path) from the source node.  Since word ladders are reversible, you could try running a breadth-first search from the end word, tagging each word with how many hops away it is from the ending word.  As you do this, you can keep track of the word you've found that's as far away as possible from the start word.  Once you're done, you can then output that word as a word whose distance is as far as possible from the start word.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi ! But what is the startword ? Because my BFS function takes a start and endword.

Comment: @mrjasmin- You'll need to change your function.  The algorithm I described above is a modified version of BFS, so you will need to update your code appropriately.

Comment: Hi ! I have found a solution. I just do a BFS from the endWord until the queue is empty :)